# Make a validation form that checks a textbox against a series of passwords in database (like excel)

Tags: users

Here is the story: I have distributed a series of tickets in real life for my customers that the tickets has a printed number on it. So customers should visit my website in order to enter the numbers of the tickets (as a password) to have access and benefit the promoted content (like polls, galleries and so) of the website.

I have all the ticket numbers stored in an excel file.
I want to know that what is the simplest way to have a form to validate a text box against that excel file? Is there any ready-t-use module for this? Or I should find a programmer to develop some?

I am newbie to Drupal 7 but I am familiar with **Content Access**, **Promoted Content** and such modules. 
Any suggestions?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: No module that I know of, but it should be quite simple to do with a custom module.

Comment: @2pha could you elaborate this? i am in need of help with this in an emergency way! :)

Comment: Make a module that checks the input code against the database (or in your case an excel file) and if true, give the user a role. Make this role have access to your promoted content. This is about as far as I can go without actually writing the module. I am available for freelance work though.

Comment: @2pha thanks for your comment and offer :) how much time does it take to make that module?